# Atualizar valor de campo no MySql usando o PHP if condition

Tags: php, html, sql

Tenho uma tabela no MySql de nome "**Cadastro**" onde a mesma possui os seguintes campos:

- **id** - Tipo: Auto Increment - Primary Key
- **dataCadastro** - Tipo: Date
- **statusFK** - Valores 1 (Ativado) e 2 (Desativado) ---> *No caso este campo esta relacionado a uma tabela chamada "status" ou seja, é um Foreing Key dentro da tabela "cadastro")*

No caso eu criei uma página index.php com uma tabela em HTML com esses três campos e gostaria que quando o campo "**dataCadastro**" for menor que a data atual, o campo **statusFK** fosse atualizado automaticamente para o valor 2 (desativado).

Entretanto, estou utilizando o seguinte código abaixo porém o mesmo esta atualizando todos os valores do campo "**statusFK**" para 2 (desativado) o que no caso seria somente o campo com data inferior a data de hoje:

```
if ( date('Y-m-d',strtotime($row['dataCadastro'])) < date('Y-m-d')){

$connection->query("UPDATE Cadastro SET statusFK = '2'");

}
```

Abaixo é o código de conexão ao banco de dados onde a tabela **Cadastro** esta localizada:

```
<?php

$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysystem;charset=utf8;', $username, $password );

?>
```

Como poderia alterar o meu código acima para tal? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você terá um resultado melhor usando a classe DateTime() do php. O funcionamento dela é simples e permite a comparação entre datas de forma pratica. Vou descrever o uso padrão, e você adapta as suas necessidades, ok? ;)

A sintaxe basica é:

```
$dataAtual = new DateTime();
$dataComparacao = new DateTime($row['dataCadastro']);
```

Para consiguir imprimir a data, use o metodo "format", como abaixo:

```
$dataAtual->format('//Formato que a data e/ou hora devem aparecer');
```

Para comparar as datas, basta seguir a mesma logica que estava usando. Com isso você ja vai ser capaz de comparar suas datas e também de verificar se as datas estão sendo setadas corretamente.

Se não conseguir, comenta ai que tento deixar mais claro pra você.